# How can I find a Powershell's running directory in a GPO?

Tags: windows, authentication, powershell, gpo

I have a powershell script that runs in a GPO. It needs to open a text file, also inside that GPO. I can't get the path information for the text file because the script doesn't execute in the same directory the script is.

I need to open the text file somehow. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully understand what you're trying to do, but if I've guessed right then you want the path of the script while its been executed?
If that's the case then use this variable:

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```